How do I add a random word from my dictionary?
Good afternoon. I want to make sure that when adding a post to the site, the name is formed from a random word or phrase (from my dictionary - a set of words) and tags. Now I have made the name of the post to be created from categories and tags, but so often the names of the post are duplicated.
<?php

namespace Submitters;

use App;
use User;
use Lang;

class Submitter {
   
   use \Purify;
   use \Prepare;
   use \Stats;
   
   protected $app;
   protected $sql;
   protected $raw;
   protected $type;
   protected $post;
   protected $user;
   protected $notes;
   protected $output;

   public function __construct(App $app, $type) 
   {

      $this->app     = $app;
      $this->sql     = $app->make('db');
      $this->user    = $app->make('user');
      $this->http    = $app->make('http');
      $this->note    = $app->make('notes');
      $this->config  = $app->make('config');
      $this->web     = $app->make('webdata');

      $this->submissionDisabled();
      User::can('submit.content') ?: App::Redirect();

      $this->type = $this->postType($type);
      $this->output = $this->prepareData();
      
      App::createTempdirDir();
      $this->execute();
   }

   private function submissionDisabled() {
      $can = $this->config->get('disable_submission') && ! User::isAdmin();
      $can && die( Lang::get('submission_disabled') );
   }
   
   protected function countTags($tags) {
      $tagsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',',$tags));
      if ($this->config->get('tags_limit') && (sizeof($tagsArray) > $this->config->get('tags_limit')) ) {
         die(Lang::get('maxtags_error'));
      }
   }
   
   protected function addTags($tags) {
      $tagsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',',$tags));
      foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) { if (empty($tag)) continue;
         if (!$this->sql->countRows('tags', 'keyword=?', $tag)) {
            $this->sql->insert('tags', ['keyword' => $tag]);
         }
      }
   }

   private function isDraft() {
      return $this->post('saveas') === "draft";
   }
   
   private function prepareData() {

      $username = $this->user->get('username', $this->post('nick'));

      $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
          'title'    => [
              'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
              'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW
          ],
          'category' => [
            'filter'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
            'default' => ''
          ],
          'tags'     => [
              'filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK, 
              'options' => function($json) { 
                  return $this->prepareTags($json);
              }
          ],
          'desc'     => [
              'filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK, 
              'default' => '',
              'options' => function($desc) { 
                  return $this->purifyDescription($desc);
              }
          ]
      ]);












      return (object) array_merge($input, [
          'time'   => time(),
          'type'   => $this->type,
          'logged' => $this->user->logged,
          'status' => $this->getUserStatus(),
          'user'   => $this->isValid('user', $username),


          'title'  => $this->isValid('title', $input['category']. ' ' .$input['tags'])


          //'title'  => $this->isValid('title', $input['title'])
      ]);
      
   }


















   
   private function getUserStatus() {

      if ($this->isDraft()) { return -1; }
      
      /* -------------------------------------------

      -2 - Hidden     // Visibility: invisible
      -1 - Draft      // Visibility: invisible
       0 - Moderation // Visibility: invisible
       1 - Moderation // Visibility: profiles
       2 - Published  // Visibility: everywhere

      */
      
      $conf = $this->config->find('in_profile,autoaccept');
      
      if ($this->user->logged) {
         if ($this->user->isadmin || $conf->autoaccept) { return 2; }
         if ($conf->in_profile) { return 1; }
      }
      
      return 0;

   }
   
   private function isValid($field, $value) {

      $i = 0; $error = 0;
      $ruleset = $this->getRules( $field );
      
      if ($ruleset) {
         
         foreach ( $ruleset as $rule => $cond ) {
            
            switch ($rule) {
               case 'not_empty': if (empty($value)) { $error++; } break;
               case 'regex_test': if (!preg_match($cond[0], $value)) { $error++; } break;
               case 'min_length': if (strlen($value) < $cond[0]) { $error++; } break;
               case 'max_length': if (strlen($value) > $cond[0]) { $error++; } break;
               case 'callback': 
                  $fieldnc = (gettype($cond) === 'array') ? $cond[0] : $cond;
                  if (call_user_func($fieldnc, $value)) { $error++; } break;
            } 
            
            if ($error) { 
               $info = $cond[1];
               die($this->Error($info) ?: $info);
            } 
            
            $i++; 

         } // END loop
         
      } // if $ruleset
      
      if (! $error) return $value;
      
   }
   
   private function getRules($field) {
      
      $rules = [

         'user' => [
            'not_empty' => [ true, Lang::get('empty_username') ],
            'min_length' => [ $this->config->get('user_minlen') , Lang::get('user_minlen') ],
            'max_length' => [ $this->config->get('user_maxlen') , Lang::get('user_maxlen') ],
            'regex_test' => [ '/^[0-9A-Za-z_-]+$/i' , Lang::get('login_invalid') ],
            'callback' => function($value) {
                if (! $this->user->logged && User::userExists($value) ) {
                    $this->Error('username_taken');
                }
            }
         ],

         'title' => [
            'not_empty' => [ true, Lang::get('empty_title') ],
            'min_length' => [ $this->config->get('title_minlen') , Lang::get('title_minlen') ],
            'max_length' => [ $this->config->get('title_maxlen') , Lang::get('title_maxlen') ]
         ]

      ];
      
      return isset($rules[ $field ]) ? $rules[ $field ] : false;
     
   }
  
   protected function mkSaveDir($dir) {
     if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        $oldmask = umask(0);
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        umask($oldmask);
      }
   }
   
   protected function makeFolder($postID) {
      
      $date = DATE . '/' . $postID;
      $path = SAVE_DIR . '/' . $postID;
      $save = PATH_SAVE .'/'. $postID;
      
      $this->mkSaveDir($save);
      
      return (object) ['save' => $save, 'date' => $date, 'path' => $path];

   }
   
   protected function moveFiles($destination) {
      foreach (glob(PATH_TEMP.'/*') as $file) {
         rename($file, $destination .'/'. basename($file));
      } return glob( $destination .'/*' );
   }
   
   protected function clearFolder() {
      if ( is_dir(PATH_TEMP) ) {
         $files = glob(PATH_TEMP . '/*');
         foreach( $files as $file ) {
            if ( is_file($file) ) { unlink($file); }
         } @rmdir(PATH_TEMP);
      }
   }
   
   private function postType($type) {
      $types = ['article', 'gif', 'gifimg','photos', 'video','audio','embed'];
      return in_array($type, $types) ? $type : exit;
   }
   
   protected function Error($e) {

      $error = [
         'no_images' => Lang::get('art_add_photo'), 
         'submit_error' => Lang::get('post_submit_error'),
         'title_invalid' => Lang::get('title_invalid_chars'),
         'img_invalid_url' => Lang::get('img_invalid_url'),
         'title_min_length' => Lang::get('title_minlen'),
         'login_used' => Lang::get('username_taken'),
         'login_invalid' => Lang::get('login_invalid'),
         'user_min_len' => Lang::get('user_minlen'),
         'user_max_len' => Lang::get('user_maxlen'),
         'desc_length' => Lang::get('art_too_short'),
      ]; 
      
      if (isset($error[$e])) { die($error[$e]); }
      return false;

   }
   
} // END Class

I made the name of the post to be created from categories and tags, but so often the names of the post are duplicated.
'title'  => $this->isValid('title', $input['category']. ' ' .$input['tags'])


Please edit your code to a minimal reproducible example. As far as I understand, you are asking about randomization in one of the post properties. Your whole error handling, handling of file type etc. are not relevant to the problem.

How much possible variants you have? Increase possible category and tags to 10,000,000,000 to have more random values. Other than that - check if this combination exist and if so - re-randomize

No, a lot of categories are not an option. I want to add a random word from the dictionary instead of categories. I just need to figure out where to put it. There will be about 10 words. How do I remove the code for the spoiler?

What is your actual question? Where is your actual problem? Your code doesn't really help either, because it's both incomplete and there's stuff that's probably unused.

Your code is unrelated to the question at hand - can you provide an example of what your dictionary data looks like? From there, people can give suggestions on how to pick a random word from that list. As it stands, your question and your code provided do not give enough information for a useful answer.

Here is a function:
private function getRandomWordFromDictionary() {
    $randomWords = array("apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", 
    "pineapple");
    
    $randomIndex = array_rand($randomWords, 1);
    $randomWord = $randomWords[$randomIndex];
    
    // Return the randomly chosen word
    return $randomWord;
}


This answer does seem to address what the author asked for. Given that they weren't too sure of what a solution could be, your answer could be further improved by providing some explanation of what your code is doing - either through inline comments, or giving some explanatory text about your answer.

Hello I think you should try this :
protected function prepareData() {
  $username = $this->user->get('username', $this->post('nick'));

  $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    'title'    => [
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags'  => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW
    ],
    'category' => [
        'filter'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
        'default' => ''
    ],
    'tags'     => [
        'filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK, 
        'options' => function($json) { 
            return $this->prepareTags($json);
        }
    ],
    'desc'     => [
        'filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK, 
        'default' => '',
        'options' => function($desc) { 
            return $this->purifyDescription($desc);
        }
    ]
]);

// Generate a random word or phrase from your dictionary
$randomWord = $this->getRandomWordFromDictionary(); // Implement this method

// Combine the random word, category, and tags to form the title
$title = $randomWord . ' ' . $input['category'] . ' ' . $input['tags'];

return (object) array_merge($input, [
    'title'  => $this->isValid('title', $title),
    'time'   => time(),
    'type'   => $this->type,
    'logged' => $this->user->logged,
    'status' => $this->getUserStatus(),
    'user'   => $this->isValid('user', $username)
]);

}

Thanks for the hint, now it remains to add the function itself. I do so, but does not add a word.-------           private function getRandomWordFromDictionary() {
$randomWords = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$randomWord = array_rand($randomWords, 1);
}
